# using mysql datediff with an elseif or case statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following line of code that can either return one of 2 conditions ('Expired','Active'). I needed to use `DATEDIFF` to figure out the dates I needed.

However, now I need to alter this code so that I can add a sort of else if condition if neither of the 2 conditions are met and result to 'Unknown'.

I have this so far:

```
SELECT        
IF(DATEDIFF(@endDate:=ADDDATE(h.StartDate,Interval h.NumMonth Month),NOW())<0,'Expired', 
        IF(DATEDIFF(@endDate,NOW())<120,'Expires in 120 days or less','Active')) AS bActive 
FROM ...
```

So, for now, I have Expired, Active but I also want to include else 'Unknown' to be included as option. How would I alter this logic? Do I need to use `ELSEIF` or `CASE`? What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` instead of `if`.  First, `case` is ANSI standard, so it works across databases.  Second, it handles multiple conditions better.  I think your logic is:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(h.StartDate, Interval h.NumMonth Month), NOW()) < 0
             THEN 'Expired'
             WHEN DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(h.StartDate, Interval h.NumMonth Month), NOW()) < 120
             THEN 'Expires in 120 days or less'
             ELSE 'Active'
        END) AS bActive
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've implemented as you suggested, however, I'm returning a null value still where I was expecting 'Active'.

Comment: @oramel . . . The statement cannot return a `NULL` value as it is written.  The `else` clause in the `case` statement ensures that a value is assigned in all three cases.